# Hide/show questions based on choices in a ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, toggle

My code:

```html
<form action="code" method="get">
<br><h6>My question here:<br>
<input name="example" value="yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
<input name="example" value="no" type="radio">No<br></h6>
<h6>Please enter the information below:</h6>
<input name="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" type="email"><br><br>
<input name="phone" placeholder="(###)###-####" type="tel">
<br><br><input value="Continue" type="submit">
</form>
```

Now I need to add JavaScript that would hide input phone and email unless they select yes for my question. I am really bad in JavaScript, I can read it but not write it from scratch.  It will need to be something like:

```js
function change_attributes(myform){
    if(myform.ratio.selectedIndex === yes){
        myform.input(phone) = .show;
        myform.input(email) = .show;
    }else{
        myform.input(phone) = .hiden;
        myform.input(email) = .hiden;
    }
 }
```

Comment: you seem to be missing an event to actually trigger that change. something needs to call change_attributes for it to run after all.

Comment: Why does this feel like its your home work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery:

Add a wrapper around the section you want to show/hide. The use jQuery's toggle function.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

jQuery:

```
$('[name="example"]').click(function () {
        $('#optionalInfo').toggle((this.value == 'yes'))
})
```

HTML:

```
<form action="code" method="get">
    <br>
     <h6>My question here:<br>
<input name="example" value="yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
<input name="example" value="no" type="radio">No<br></h6>

    <div id="optionalInfo">

<h6>Please enter the information below:</h6>

        <input name="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" type="email">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input name="phone" placeholder="(###)###-####" type="tel">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <input value="Continue" type="submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#optionalInfo{
    display: none;
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/csroot23/

Comment: I see that all these codes work. But can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? It doesn't work on my test page. I put in the css and put in the <script> into the head. And it doesn't react? But on any of these jsfiddles it all works. Even tried linking to a example.js and putting the js in there.

Comment: If you're adding the scripts to the head you need to wrap the JS with $(document).ready (function (){ code here }) else it fires before the items exist in the DOM so when the code runs there are no elements to attach events to.

Comment: Thanks.  Me being a noob to JS I never knew you can't put the code in the header(unless wrapped).  I just put the code at the end of the page and it worked.  Thanks So much.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure JavaScript (no jQuery) solution, then here you go:

```js
var radio = document.getElementsByName('example');

var inputContainer = document.getElementById('inputContainer');
var phoneInput = document.getElementById('phone');

for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; ++i) {
  radio[i].onclick = function() {
    if (this.value == "yes") {
      inputContainer.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      inputContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="code" method="get">
  <br>
  <h6>My question here:<br>
<input name="example" value="yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
<input name="example" value="no" type="radio">No<br></h6>
  <div id="inputContainer">
    <h6>Please enter the information below:</h6>
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" type="email">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="(###)###-####" type="tel">
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <input value="Continue" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I see that all these codes work.  But can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? It doesn't work on my test page. I put in the `id="inputContainer"` and put in the `<script>` into the head.  And it doesn't react?  But on any of these jsfiddles it all works.

Comment: If you press F12 in your browser, you should see some developer tools open up [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/fQRv6kM). There's a console tab which shows JavaScript errors, that might help. If you're using jQuery then you need to wrap the code in $(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE });

Comment: To use JavaScript, you're probably going to need to put the script below the HTML, but if that doesn't work, try see if there are any errors in the console tab of the Developer Tools.

Comment: I use the Element Inspector all the time but not the console.  Thanks to all, but I used the jQuery method mentioned above.  Thanks for your help too.

Answer (score 1):

You would bind an event handler for the `change` event for the radio buttons. There you can check which of the radio buttons are selected, and use the `show` or `hide` method on the elements. (There are variations of this, some nicer and shorter, but this is pretty close to your pseudo code):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[name=example]').change(function(){
    if ($('input[name=example]:checked').attr('value') === 'yes') {
      $('input[name=phone]').show();
      $('input[name=email]').show();
    } else {
      $('input[name=phone]').hide();
      $('input[name=email]').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="code" method="get">
<br><h6>My question here:<br>
<input name="example" value="yes" type="radio" checked>Yes<br>
<input name="example" value="no" type="radio">No<br></h6>
<h6>Please enter the information below:</h6>
<input name="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" type="email"><br><br>
<input name="phone" placeholder="(###)###-####" type="tel">
<br><br><input value="Continue" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you use jQuery.

```
function change_attributes(myform){
        if(myform.ratio.selectedIndex === 'yes'){
            myform.find('input[name=phone]').show();
            myform.find('input[name=email]').show();
        }else{
            myform.find('input[name=phone]').hide();
            myform.find('input[name=email]').hide();
        }
     }
```

Comment: with jquery, you wouldnt even need it in the function, that probalby makes it harder in some cases.
$('myForm').change(function(){ CODE HERE }) should work outside of a function

Comment: @Ryan, it can be used even through `$("select .show")` for example

Comment: @Romankozin  sorry, hit enter out of habbit before i was done. ya, it would probably work, though puttin it in jQuery(document).ready(function($)
 would probably be best

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this ?

```
<form action="code" method="get">
    <h6>My question here:</h6>
    <input name="example" value="yes" type="radio" onclick="$('#to-hide').show();">Yes<br />
    <input name="example" value="no" type="radio" onclick="$('#to-hide').hide();">No<br />
    <div id="to-hide" style="display: none;">
        <h6>Please enter the information below:</h6>
        <input name="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" type="email"><br><br>
        <input name="phone" placeholder="(###)###-####" type="tel">
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <input value="Continue" type="submit">
</form>
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt4bbbgd/1/)

Comment: I even tried yours. The jsfiddle works but when I put it to my page nothing happens.

Comment: Could you provide your full example (using gist or pastebin) so we can see what's wrong with it ?